# How to properly serialize a PrimaryKeyRelatedField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail-streamfield

I have two Django models:

1. **Book** -- which has some Wagtail StreamFields:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover_image = StreamField(...)
    ...
```

2. **Publisher** -- which is pure Django:

```py
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

I wanted to have a PublisherChooser in my Wagtail admin. So I [created all that was required and then] added a field to my Book model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover_image = StreamField(...)
    ...
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("title"),
        FieldPanel("cover_image"),
        FieldPanel("publisher", widget=PublisherChooser),
    ]
```

Now I have a proper PublisherChooser whenever I want to create a Book in Wagtail Admin.

**Problem**

Now I want to serialize my Book model. So I have tried:

```py
class PublisherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = [
            "name",
            ...
        ]
    name = serializers.CharField()
    ...
```

and

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            "title",
            "cover_image",
            ...,
            "publisher",
    
    publisher = serializer.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Publisher.objects.all())

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        publisher = validated_data.pop("publisher")
        instance.publisher_id = publisher.id
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        publisher_serializer = PublisherSerializer(
            Publisher, context={"pk": instance.publisher}
        )
        data["publisher"] = publisher_serializer.data
        return data
```

I get publisher in the response but the publisher data doesn't seem to look right:

```json
"publisher": {
            "name": "<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f9ffa146310>",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add many=True in your PrimaryKeyRelatedField

```py
publisher = serializer.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Publisher.objects.all(), many=True)
```

This will probably fix your issue